# Dwnload map image with python

Tags: python, google-maps, parsing, urllib

I am trying to download map image in **python** with **urllib** module. But it always failed.

- I'm tried to use `urllib.urlopen()` with some parameter variants
- tried in `urllib.urlretrieve()`

But it doesn't work.
 And, When I see the source code of image url, I didn't find image file. Here is image: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=31.0456,121.3997&zoom=12&size=320x385&sensor=false

Source code:

```
#-------------------------- PARSE IP ADDRESS  -------------------------------
import re
import urllib


try:
    mysite = urllib.urlopen('http://ip-api.com/line')
except urllib.HTTPError, e:
    print "Cannot retrieve URL: HTTP Error Code", e.code
except urllib.URLError, e:
   print "Cannot retrieve URL: " + e.reason[1]

list_of_params = mysite.read()
print list_of_params
ip_arr = list_of_params.splitlines()

#--------------------- HERE IS FIND MAP IMAGE --------------------------------------
try:
    map_page = urllib.urlopen('http://ip-api.com')
except urllib.HTTPError, e:
    print "Cannot retrieve URL: HTTP Error Code", e.code
except urllib.URLError, e:
    print "Cannot retrieve URL: " + e.reason[1]

#f = open("data.html", "w")
#f.write(str(mysite.read()))
#f.close()

#looking for this in page
pattern = re.findall(re.compile("url\(\'(https://maps\.googleapis\.com/maps/api/staticmap\?center=.*)\'"), page_get_map.read())
map_img_url = pattern[0].replace('&amp;', '&')

#-------------------    DOWNLOAD MAP IMAGE And SAVE IT  ------------------------
#file_name = map_img_url.rsplit('/',1)[1]

try:
    get_map_img = urllib.urlretrieve(map_img_url, "staticmap.png")
except urllib.HTTPError, e:
    print "Cannot retrieve URL: HTTP Error Code", e.code
except urllib.URLError, e:
    print "Cannot retrieve URL: " + e.reason[1]


i = open("pict.png", "w")
i.write(get_map_img.read())
i.close()

print "End of file"
```

Comment: Cannot download image

Comment: Paste full stacktrace

Answer (score 4):

```
import requests
f=open('static.png','wb')
f.write(requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=31.0456,121.3997&zoom=12&size=320x385&sensor=false').content)
f.close()
```

Comment: that worked brilliantly for me. Do you if /how bird-eye views could be downloaded fromm google maps in a similar manner?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you parsing the map URL? Construct it yourself:

```
import json, urllib

query = '' # IP to get coordinates of, leave empty for current IP

geo = urllib.urlopen('http://ip-api.com/json/%s?fields=240' % query)
result = json.load(geo)
if result['zip']:
    zoom = 13
elif result['city']:
    zoom = 12
else:
    zoom = 6
map_img_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=%s,%s&zoom=%i&size=320x385&sensor=false" % (result['lat'], result['lon'], zoom)
get_map_img = urllib.urlretrieve(map_img_url, "staticmap.png")
```